# The theory/algorithm knowledge behind the built-in Discretize* and Boundary*

Tags: computational-geometry, implementation-details

The `ComputationalGeometry` package was built-in in V10 distribution.

In classical computational geometry field, the following questions were investigated.

- Convex hulls, `ConvexHullMesh[]`
- Line segment intersection, `` Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[] ``
- Point location, `RegionMember[]`
- Voronoi diagrams, `VoronoiMesh[]`
- Delaunay triangulations, `DelaunayMesh[]`
- Boolean operations(like union, difference and intersection), `RegionUnion[], RegionDifference[], RegionIntersection[]`

[image]

which means I can find the **theory/algorithm** in classical textbook of computational geometry like: "*Computational Geometry, Algorithms and Applications"*.

In addtion, new version also owns other new functionality, like: `Discretize*, Boundary*`

- `DiscretizeGraphics[]`
- `BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[]`
- `DiscretizeRegion[]`
- `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[]`
- `RegionBoundary[]`

---

So I would like to know:

- Is it possible to know the **theory/algorithm** behind the above functions. Namely, which textbook involved the **theory/algorithm** knowledge?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`DiscretizeRegion[]` and `ToElementMesh[]` at their core use `TriangleLink` and `TetGenLink` to make the mesh. Have a look at the documentation for specifics about these packages. Both ship with source code. As far as literature goes. Have a look at "[Delaunay Mesh Generation](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/meshpapers/delnotes.pdf)" by Jonathan Shewchuk (Author) *et al*.

Package homepage

- [Triangle](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html) : A Two-Dimensional Quality Mesh Generator and Delaunay Triangulator
- [TetGen](http://wias-berlin.de/software/tetgen/): A Quality Tetrahedral Mesh Generator and a 3D Delaunay Triangulator

Comment: Thanks for your explanation about `DiscretizeGraphics[], DiscretizeGraphics[]`.  I know the boundary coordinates could be achieved via *built-in* `RegionBoundary[]`,  is it possible to know its thorry?

Comment: I suppose you mean for the symbolic case? There, I believe, it constructs CAD cells, but I am not sure. For the numeric case, the boundary is sampled, this was developed in house so I don't think there are papers.

Comment: No, @user21 I don't care about the **symbolic** case, rather than the **numerical** case. Anyway, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what algorithms the built-in functions implement, but here are a few books that implement some of the algorithms you seek:

[Computational Geometry: Algorithms and Applications](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540779736)

[Computational Geometry in C](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521649765)

[Discrete and Computational Geometry](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691145539)

[Computational Geometry: An Introduction](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387961313)

Finally, there is this one that deals with shape analysis:

[Mathematical Tools for Shape Analysis and Description](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1627053638)